# How to render local images according to the id of the items fetched from url?

Tags: react-native, axios, nodes

I have created an images folder in assets and I have saved some pictures in it. And I wanted to render those pictures according to the id of the items that I have fetched from the URL, I renamed all those picture according the id of the items fetched. But it is not working. Can anybody help me to figure out or if you have another suggestion to do it I am open for suggestions? Here you can see what I am trying to do:

```
export default function App() {
      const [material, setMateral] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:5000/materals/")
          .then((products) => {
            setMaterial(materials.data.response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      }, []);
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {material.map((material) => {
            console.log(material);
            const { id, name, categories, genders, brands, price } = material;
            <View style={styles.materialsContainer}>
              <View style={styles.materialsItem}>
                <Image
                  source={"../../assets/images/${id}.jpg"}
                  alt={id}
                  style={styles.thumbnail}
                />
                <Text style={styles.box} numberOfLines={1}>
                  ${id}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.box}${name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.box}${categories}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.box}${genders}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.box}${brands}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.box}$ ${price}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>;
          })}
     );
    }
```

[image: Here is what I got in the console]

Comment: Can you share the output of `materials.data.response` And what's `data` here in `data.map(...)`?

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for your answer. I am getting some object in the console but it's not rendering in the page,. Any suggestion?

Comment: I have edit the post and put the link for what I am getting in the console. About the data it just a mistake and I have changed it to material.

Comment: Well, I guess @bjjeong fix the problems you got as I want to tell you so check out it :)

Comment: Oliver thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```js
<Image
    source={"../../assets/images/${id}.jpg"}
    alt={id}
    style={styles.thumbnail}
/>
```

You should be using [backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (``) rather than double quotation to perform string interpolation.

```js
<Image
    source={`../../assets/images/${id}.jpg`}
    alt={id}
    style={styles.thumbnail}
/>
```

I'm also not sure what you're trying to do in your Text components

```js
<Text style={styles.box}${name}</Text>
```

Are you trying to add a '$' as a string before the name? If you're trying to perform string interpolation, the `${}` format only works when using backticks. But in this case, you could just do this.

```js
<Text style={styles.box}>{name}</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help bjjeong, the problem is solved.